# Calculate the vector component

Tags: code-golf, math, geometry

### Challenge

Assume two vectors \$\mathbf{a} = (a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n)\$ and \$\mathbf{b} = (b_1,b_2,\cdots,b_n)\$ are given in an \$n\$-dimensional space, where at least one of \$b_1,\cdots,b_n\$ is nonzero. Then \$\mathbf{a}\$ can be uniquely decomposed into two vectors, one being a scalar multiple of \$\mathbf{b}\$ and one perpendicular to \$\mathbf{b}\$:

$$
\mathbf{a} = \mathbf{b}x + \mathbf{b^\perp}\text{, where }\mathbf{b^\perp} \cdot \mathbf{b}=0.
$$

Given \$\mathbf{a}\$ and \$\mathbf{b}\$ as input, find the value of \$x\$.

This can be also thought of as the following: Imagine a line passing through the origin and the point \$\mathbf{b}\$. Then draw a perpendicular line on it that passes through the point \$\mathbf{a}\$, and denote the intersection \$\mathbf{c}\$. Finally, find the value of \$x\$ that satisfies \$\mathbf{c}=\mathbf{b}x\$.

You can use an explicit formula too (thanks to @xnor), which arises when calculating the [projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra)#Finding_projection_with_an_inner_product):

$$
x=\frac{\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b}}{\mathbf{b} \cdot \mathbf{b}}
$$

Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply. The shortest code in bytes wins.

### Example

Here is an example in 2D space, where `a=(2,7)` and `b=(3,1)`. Observe that `(2,7) = (3.9,1.3) + (-1.9,5.7)` where `(3.9,1.3)` is equal to `1.3b` and `(-1.9,5.7)` is perpendicular to `b`. Therefore, the expected answer is `1.3`.

[image]

### Test cases

```
a         b          answer
(2,7)     (3,1)      1.3
(2,7)     (-1,3)     1.9
(3,4,5)   (0,0,1)    5
(3,4,5)   (1,1,1)    4
(3,4,5)   (1,-1,-1)  -2
(3,4,5,6) (1,-2,1,2) 1.2
```

Comment: Will the values of the input vectors always be integers?

Comment: @Noodle9 No, it may have non-integers.

Comment: Can we take the dimension \$n\$ as additional argument?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen No, unless you're using [pointer+length input](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13262/78410).

Answer (score 25):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 1 byte<sup>[SBCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SBCS)</sup>

```apl
⌹
```

[Check all test cases!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1HPzv9pCo/aJig86u171NV8aL3xo7aJj/qmFhclA8mSjMzi/0YK5gppCsYKhlwQ1qH1hgrGXMYKJgqmQJ4BEBrCeYYgiMQDqQViqIgZVMwISBoBAA) When used dyadically, `X ⌹ Y` solves the least squares<sup>*</sup> system \$Ya = X\$ for a result \$a\$ of the appropriate shape, e.g.:

- if \$Y\$ is a matrix and \$X\$ is a vector, we try to solve a linear system of equations.
- if \$Y\$ and \$X\$ are matrices, we compute \$Y\$'s (pseudo-)inverse and multiply it on the left of \$X\$.
- when both \$X\$ and \$Y\$ are vectors, the least squares formulation reduces to what we want, namely

$$\frac{X \cdot Y}{||Y||^2}$$

<sup>*</sup>*the least squares system \$Ya = X\$* can be understood as "what should \$a\$ be such that \$Ya\$ is as close as can be to \$X\$?", where closeness is measured with the usual L2 distance.

Comment: We have a winner. I very much doubt any language can do this in 0 bytes.

Comment: If I open a file and I see that thing in it, I will mark it as virus.

Comment: @darksky a couple of months ago I would've done the exact same thing

Answer (score 8):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>33</s> 32 bytes

-1 byte thanks to @xnor!

```hs
(!)b=sum.zipWith(*)b
a#b=a!b/b!b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/X0NRM8m2uDRXryqzIDyzJENDSzOJK1E5yTZRMUk/STHpf25iZp6CrUJBUWZeiYKKQrSxjomOqY5ZrIKyQrShjq6RjqGOUex/AA)

---

## [Coconut](http://coconut-lang.org/), 35 bytes

```hs
(a,b)->p(a,b)/p(b,b)
p=sum..map$(*)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYzLDoIwEEX3fMUsXLSkVFpEIwnscOsHqAsgJRJ5NKX4SPh3bIFEk0lO7pk7U3RF1w56KuPrhDKSYy@RM7cS5QaOjPuhobTJ5Aa5eHrdq1oAixwArT4WAFUrB40w7WVdGcKYwFwXz6yeE71E/Aajm0Bpo1RVq82leBdCakjPp1SpTi3PciWyx4Q4OWBAAWEYGA2cNXuMBFYcHbPakdAon/i2FP4MI8ya3b/x7GDw@CrJftHcdLn9yL8)

Comment: Save a byte by making definition of `!` a bit less pointfree: `(!)v=sum.zipWith(*)v`

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 24 bytes

```r
function(a,b)a%*%b/b%*%b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP08jUSdJM1FVSzVJPwlE/k/TSNYw0jHX1EnWMNYx1NTkQhLQNdQxhooY65jomILEDHQM4MrggoY6htgEdUEIWVjHDCphBNRgpKn5HwA)

Comment: `lm(a~b-1)` does slightly better.

Comment: @Xi'an that's great, and it's also a principally different approach, so I'd suggest you to post it as a separate answer.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/) + `numpy`, 20 bytes

```python
lambda a,b:a@b/(b@b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZczdCsIwDAXg@z5F7kwgm2vnDwqC76FepDqx0M2yVWVPP1cVFITc5MvJCX28XJtyOG/2g5fangSE7Vq2dop2a2lwdbi2EZpbHXr1uDhfgV4rOEpXwQa86yLWErC6i2dwTbhFpLwL3kWcwISIFITWNRHP@OrIpW2lx/S/Kw7E8Kf6MH4NaHhJgCVrAp2X6rNnmssEKzWeZjwfqeAiheZf0ayTzH4lS0OQmQ/y4s1mzJrUaJ4)

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 2 bytes

```
Y\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/PzLm//9oY2vDWK5oI2vzWAA)

Least squares approach such as used in the APL answer.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>6</s> 5 bytes

```
ḋ`÷@ḋ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hju6Ew9sdgNT/w8sdjs191LQm8v//6GgjHfNYnWhjHcNYIAXl6RrqGIO5xjomOqZAhoGOAVQBTMRQxxBDRBeEEGI6ZhBRI6BSo9hYAA)

Simple translation of the given formula. Takes \$\mathbf{b}\$ as the left argument and \$\mathbf{a}\$ as the right argument.

```
ḋ        The dot product of b and
 `       itself,
  ÷@     dividing
    ḋ    the dot product of b and a.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>21</s> 18 bytes

```
Ｆ²⊞υΣＥＡ×κ§θλＩ∕⊟υ⊟υ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYs9C8IwFAB3f8UbX@A5WAcHJ9GlQyGgW8gQ2kiDaRLzUfz3T4u33HI3ziaP0XjmZ8yAnQDZyoyN4N4WHEzCPqRWURA83GILvggutQ@T/eCbwIuN805mFypeTal4c6ubLMqYsP2uv7eIWakjwUETqI7gpDXvV/8F) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes inputs in the order `b`, `a`. Explanation:

```
Ｆ²
```

Repeat twice...

```
⊞υΣＥＡ×κ§θλ
```

Input a vector, take its dot product with `b` and push the result to the predefined empty list.

```
Ｉ∕⊟υ⊟υ
```

Retrieve the dot products and take their quotient.

Comment: The previous version was lost because I happened to slip under the grace edit period by a couple of seconds, but you didn't miss much, just a one-byte golf from taking inputs in reverse order and separate a two-byte golf.

Comment: 10 bytes using the newer version of Charcoal on ATO: `Ｉ∕Σ×θηΣ×ηη` [Attempt This Online](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iOSOxKDk_MWfBgqWlJWm6FjctAooy80o0nBOLSzRcMssyU1I1gktzNUIyc1OLNQp1FDI0NXUUECIZYBEgsF5SnJRcDDVlebSSblmOUuyG6GgjHQXzWB2FaGMdBcPYWIg0AA) Link is to verbose version of code. Does not take inputs in reverse order.

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>84</s> <s>74</s></sup> 73 bytes

Saved 10 bytes thanks to [dingledooper](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/88546/dingledooper)!!!

Saved a byte thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)!!!

```c
float f(a,b,n)float*a,*b;{float x,y;for(;n--;y+=*b**b++)x+=*a++**b;x/=y;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##xZLbaoNAEIbv@xSDEPAwWo8pYWtuSp8ikbJrtVVaE9QLQ/DZ7RhdXWjobZcddMfvn/l33dT@SNNhyL9OvIVc5yiwMm4rk6Mp2HX60uGF5adaZ5Vts4sVm8I0hWUZHb1yy6IF6x7jC@uHb15UugHXB6Axibl7SCCGq49PPZtzYs4F6C057t3h5pztYbCCvhSHGK3onHXRVYsGd9k566GnsuFdNpSsPc6VjhQatysfLbxP5f2erWdhQps1bfPGJ4S7SLum8CkCipBi6SxhMcGCYEGwIFgQLAgW0Vy9qFqobtx4fkAzkDNUDUDWnbOuzd5n1nOI8JwdQkQkAlmmpfScfvLahHrqrx27V//Y7V4oIg1BXQeabHKqQR/NlCRxGT2eYcvAskp5J8ZxrgnJdU3XDLYkF2kxSQuSVocyGdWFqr7tNycW9uAaSzFypFRT22wcN6fP8ujL5FAkCtr/8mUg/Ic18Ye16e811D/X142oSrxZUsTLbsDew8bxctg0x4q6NUj/lErF620oE6nsH/rhBw)

Inputs two pointers to vectors \$a,b\$ and their dimension \$n\$ and returns their component..

Uses given formula:

$$x = \frac{a_0\cdot b_0 + a_1\cdot b_1 + \dots + a_{n-1}\cdot b_{n-1}}{b_0^2 + b_1^2 + \dots + b_{n-1}^2}$$

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
*OInO/
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fy98zz1////9oIx3zWK5oYx3DWAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfWXCoZXF/7X8D63L89f/r/M/OjraSMc8VifaWMcwNlZHAcbVNdQxhvCNdUx0TIEiBjoGMCUwIUMdQ0whXRBCEtQxgwgbARUbxcbGAgA).

Implements the given formula:

$$x = \frac{a_1\times b_1 + a_2\times b_2 + \dots + a_n\times b_n}{b_1^2 + b_2^2 + \dots + b_n^2}$$

**Explanation:**

```python
*       # Multiply the values at the same indices in the two (implicit) input-lists
 O      # Sum this list
  I     # Push the second input-list again
   n    # Square each value
    O   # Take the sum of that
     /  # And divide the two values
        # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 9 bytes

```
#.#2/#.#&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n6Zg@19ZT9lIH0io/Q8oyswrcdBKU3BwcFAISi1LLSpOVdB3UKiurjbSUTCv1VGoNtZRMKwFMeAiuoY6CsYQIaCkiY6CKYhtoKNgAFeKJA5UbIhDXBeMUWR0FMxgkkZgjUa1tbXW/wE) Pure function. Takes **b** followed by **a** as input and returns a rational number as output. It just directly uses Mathematica's notation for the dot product.

Answer (score 2):

## Fortran >= 95, 66 bytes

Taking advantage of implicit typing for the return type.

```
function x(a,b)
real a(:),b(:)
x=dot_product(a,b)/norm2(b)**2
end
```

Answer (score 1):

## [[R]](https://cran.r-project.org/), 22 bytes

Taking advantage of a resident regression function, `lm`

```r
function(a,b)lm(a~b-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcdBCoAgFEXReSv5L56RlgRBi0lDCNLAatrWrSZNLufmEqYSruTPdU8y02GLMt9OaZQgXnpaGtCLYccOqIKYWvQ4gF/eVY2tc9pzFN3Sgr@PZWo0UB4)

Answer (score 0):

## Java 10, <s>84</s> 74 bytes

```java
a->b->{float A=0,B=0;int i=0;for(var t:b){A+=a[i++]*t;B+=t*t;}return A/B;}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##lVJNa4NAEL3nVww5aV2tJv2AWAVzCPRQesgxeBgTLZuaVdwxJYi/3a7JlpQ2lRQWZth5b9682d3iHu3t5r1b5yglvCAXzQhAEhJfw1ZVnZp47mS1WBMvhLPQyVOWF0irmF0HWvRJGEIGQYd2mNhhc6xBFLhsHrg@FwRcxayojD1WQLPEbCIrwBW3rPiG/LkVkAptlVJdCYhu537b@SM1bFknuRpWz7wv@AZ2yoexpIqLt1UMaPaeACiVZIj0A/RYzYQ9tgy@30yZ15r@tWjbY9M/4VN2x@5/EFzmDghcYnjM@zfD7s8whz38Zk2U1OREa0fnT3Bc6LGLxgKyLxokerXLg6R05xQ1OaXaOuXCGD@LsiY5g7F1/iJRVeFBOlScHsdA0xoDis0gKDG1l0sqrzUpmV4lc7As84PqqZMhnrbZdp8)

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) v2.0a0, 9 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
í*V x÷Vx²
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=2.0a0&code=7SpWIHj3Vniy&input=WzMsNCw1XQpbMSwtMSwtMV0)