# Find distance between the closest 3D points

Tags: code-golf, math, geometry

Your task is to take \$n \ge 2\$ points in 3D space, represented as 3 floating point values, and output the [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) between the two closest points. For example

$$A = (0, 0, 0) \\ B = (1, 1, 1) \\ C = (4, 0, 2)$$

would output \$\sqrt3 = 1.7320508075688772...\$, the distance between \$A\$ and \$B\$.

The Euclidean distance, \$E\$, between any two points in 3D space \$X = (a_1, b_1, c_1)\$ and \$Y = (a_2, b_2, c_2)\$ is given by the formula

$$E = \sqrt{(a_2 - a_1)^2 + (b_2 - b_1)^2 + (c_2 - c_1)^2}$$

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest code in bytes wins

Comment: Restricting to a single language is hardly ever a good idea. Competition is within each language anyway

Comment: @LuisMendo sorry, I didn't know that, this is my second question yet. I will edit the question.

Comment: the coordinates are floating point, and the output is also a floating point.

Comment: I'm going to make some edits to clarify the challenge, you can revert it if you dislike them. I think that should make it able to be reopened.

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms perhaps I didn't make this clear, but it can be more or less than three points

Comment: @forever Oh, sorry. I'll fix that.

Comment: I would recommend restricting the input to positive (or non-negative) integers, as requiring float handling just complicates the challenge unnecessarily. Furthermore, why isn't the output for those three points \$\sqrt3\$ between \$(1,1,1)\$ and \$(0,0,0)\$?

Comment: I've edited your question to improve the formatting (including mathjax etc.). Feel free to roll these back if you dislike them. I'd recommend adding in a few test cases, and to clarify my above question, but beyond that, I don't see any major issues left.

Comment: Suggested test case: `[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[1,1,1]]` (looping over all n^2 combinations and filtering zero distance is not sufficient)

Comment: Adding some more testcases would be nice.

Comment: Fixed example, please feel free to revert (with an explaination why it it's as you say).

Comment: "between the two closest points" - if two given points are are co-located are they to be considered as different points? Or may we assume that the input is a set of co-ordinates?

Comment: @JonathanAllan they are two different points.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 8 bytes

```
œ€ü-nOtß
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6ORHTWsO79HN8y85PP///@hoAx0gjNWB04Y6QAikTYB8o9hYAA)

**Commented**:

```python
œ         # take all permutations of the input
 €        # for each permutation:
   -      #   take the element-wise difference
  ü       #   between each pair of adjacent points
    n     # square each number
     O    # sum all difference-lists
      t   # take the square root of every sum
       ß  # take the minimum
```

Answer (score 11):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 34 bytes

```r
function(...)min(dist(rbind(...)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfm5mXkllcYvs/rTQvuSQzP09DT09PEyiqARLWKEoCyoOFNDVhajWSNQx0gFBTJ1nDUAcIQQwToIiRpiYXFjVoijW5/gMA)

This is a nice opportunity to use [R](https://www.r-project.org/)'s `...` syntax to define a function that can accept a variable number of arguments; in this case, the `x,y,z` coordinates of each point.

The `dist` function calculates the pairwise distance between all rows of a matrix, using a chosen method - luckily, the default is 'euclidean' and so isn't specified in this case.

Of course, it could be even shorter if we allow the input to already be combined-together as a matrix, but this wouldn't be so neat...

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 23 bytes

```r
function(m)min(dist(m))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfm5mXkllcYvs/rTQvuSQzP08jVxMopgESBDI1/xfkZ@aVFMfnJpYUZVbYFiUB1WskaxjoAKGmTrKGoQ4QghgmQBEjTU0uqIEaKPo0uQgYg2YeTmP@AwA)

Comment: Looks like exactly right tool for this task.

Comment: I don't think I'd seen the `...` syntax used for golfing before. You should add it to the [tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/4024/86301) thread!

Answer (score 9):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 33 bytes

```
Min[Norm[#-#2]&@@@#~Subsets~{2}]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73zczL9ovvyg3WllX2ShWzcHBQbkuuDSpOLWkuK7aqDZW7X9AUWZeCVDaLs1BOVatLjg5Ma@umqu62kAHCGt1uBSqDXWAEMwyAYoZ1QKZyNLoCmu5av8DAA)

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <sup><s>106</s> <s>95</s></sup> 93 bytes

Saved 11 bytes thanks to [fireflame241](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/68261/fireflame241)!!!
Saved 2 bytes thanks to [Jonathan Allan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53748/jonathan-allan)!!!

```python
lambda l:min(sum((a-b)**2for a,b in zip(l[p],v))**.5for q,v in enumerate(l)for p in range(q))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVDBboMwDL3zFbkRV6YK0Klate5HKIdAzYoGISWh2ob4dpYAPeywXJ79nu1nR3/bW6fSuTpf5ka2xVWy5tTWipuh5VxGBex2SdX1TGLBasV@as2bTOf4AKfsX7x0x4eXSA0t9dISb8DT2pO9VB/E7wCzJWMNOzOecYECY0AeOxQOBSYbCkwhx7VC/Fvh@P2q/K2Nl6kHlyeQQ0BfmkpLV2@a@GVRuLbURxCUNyo/qfdaeBmS46EMkS1RnIauV5u66ZSTY4peA3@PRXr@wHILsqcBnALmnr@u4haWxLvKwnCKzErovlaWV@FoJxa9s9FMbNyWyK5vm18@hTD/Ag)

Inputs a list of points as tuples and returns the Euclidean distance between the two closest points.
Works with points of any dimension so long as they are consistent within the list.

Comment: [WLOG, let p<q](https://tio.run/##dVBNb4MwDL3zK3LDrkwVoNO0at0foRz4CCtaCIGk0jbEb2cJUE07LJdnv2f72dFf9tardGku10UWXVkXTJ67VoG5dwBFVOLhkDT9yAoqWavYd6tBZjonmQ05OvH45NXBa2Oh3gVIoUAielb/sgPiYoWxhl0YZMCJU4wEsUPukFOyI6cUc9oq@L8Vjj9uyt/aeJ16cnmCOQbiU4vKitqbJn5X4q4t9REG1U1UH2L0Wni9J8@nKiS2RnEaul5tWtkrJ8ciegn8PZbE4w/WW4g9DPAcMPf8dQ1YXBPvWpQGRGQ2Qo@tstCEk51Z9MYmM7NpXyKrX3e/fA5x@QE)

Comment: My suggestion was to take `p in range(q)`, removing the need for the not-equal check.

Comment: Save two with `enumerate`, [TIO](https://tio.run/##dVDBboMwDL3zFbkRV6YK0Klate5HKIdAzYoGISWh2ob4dpYAPeywXJ79nu1nR3/bW6fSuTpf5ka2xVWy5tTWipuh5VxGBex2SdX1TGLBasV@as2bTOf4AKfsX7x0x4eXSA0t9dISb8DT2pO9VB/E7wCzJWMNOzOecYECY0AeOxQOBSYbCkwhx7VC/Fvh@P2q/K2Nl6kHlyeQQ0BfmkpLV2@a@GVRuLbURxCUNyo/qfdaeBmS46EMkS1RnIauV5u66ZSTY4peA3@PRXr@wHILsqcBnALmnr@u4haWxLvKwnCKzErovlaWV@FoJxa9s9FMbNyWyK5vm18@hTD/Ag).

Comment: You can use `zip(p,v)` and `for p in l[:q]` to save 6 more bytes, [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY/BboMwDIbvPEVuxJWpAnSahta9COUQqFHRIKQkVNsQz84SoIcdlovtz3Z@//rb3nqVLvX5srSyK6@StVnXKG7GjnMZlXA4JHU/MIklaxT7aTTX@ACHjy@e3/HhOamxo0Fa4i14rD1s8@xewGLJWMPOjOdcoMAYkMcuChcFJnsUmEKB24T4d8Lx49b5Oxuvv55cnUABAX1pqixdvWjiL0Xh1lKfQVDdqPqkwffCy5i8nqoQ2ZrFaeh2tWnaXrl2TNFb4M1YpKf31QuypwBkAXPPu6u5hbXwqrI0nCKzAT00yvI6nOzMog82mZlN@xH59X3XK@YQll8 "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
ŒcZ_/²§Ṃ½
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8H39oU/ChrYf3Jbg93DHf4OHOpkN7/x@dlBwVr39o06HlEP7//9HRBjpAGKsDpw11gBBImwD5RrGxAA)

Works with points of any dimension

#### Explanation

```
ŒcZ_/²§Ṃ½ # Take as input a list of points, where each point is a list of coordinates
Œc        # All pairs of two distinct points [(p1,p2),(p1,p3),...]
  Z       # Transpose to get two lists of points [[p1,p1,...],[p2,p3,...]]
   _/     # Depth-1 vectorizing difference [p1-p2, p1-p3, ...]
     ²§   # Square coordinates and sum each
       Ṃ  # Minimum
        ½ # Square root
```

Comment: You can use `ÆḊ` as the norm if that helps you? Perhaps change `²§Ṃ½` to `ÆḊṂ`?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Unfortunately `ÆḊ` doesn't vectorize, so I would have to use `ÆḊ€Ṃ` for the same number of bytes

Answer (score 6):

## [Ruby 2.7](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>79</s> 65 bytes

*Saved a whooping 14 bytes, thanks to [Sisyphus](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/48931/sisyphus)!*

```ruby
->s{s.combination(2).map{_1.zip(_2).sum{|a,b|(a-b)**2}**0.5}.min}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dc/BCoMwDAbgu09R8KJSQ9paq4ftRcSDDoQe6uqch019dqe4waYu/yUk8JHcuvIxVacpPLd9C5erKXVd3PW19rgPprD9YGkzWHhq6zU@tJ3ph4KWg1eEpR8EfAwCBDmC0fU4WVJlJMuQzskpyRidszTRPOF5TnJyVC5hoARHiQkqGSeJUtz5sthqvdFZ@jRIxRZdrIhFnAkZc6EEppI5@7uOrWUF63JhXYLA8LfSHbb59v@TCDi9AA)

- Expects an array of points!
- TIO uses an older version of Ruby, so `|p,q|p,q` is replaced by `_1,_2` to save three bytes (as suggested by [Dingus](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92901/dingus)).

Comment: Nice solution! 68 by using `|a,b|` syntax and using the fact that `sum` takes a block: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dc/BCoMwDAbgu09R8KJSQ9paq4ftRcSDDoQe6uqch019dqe4waYu/yUk8JHcuvIxVacpPLd9C5erKXVd3PW19rgPprD9YGkzWHhq6zU@tJ3ph4KWg1eEpR8EfAwCBDmC0fU4WVJlJMuQzskpyRidszTRPOF5TnJyVC5hoARHiQkqGSeJUtz5sthqvdFZ@jRIxRZdrIhFnAkZc6EEppI5@7uOrWUF63JhXYLA8LfSHbb59v@TCDi9AA "Ruby – Try It Online"). Even less in 2.7 since you can use `_1` and `_2` instead of `|p,q|...`

Comment: @Sisyphus - didn't knew about that syntax!

Answer (score 4):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 14 bytes

```
{⊇Ċz-ᵐ^₂ᵐ+√}ᶠ⌋
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRu/6htw6Ompoe7Omsfbp3wv/pRV/uRripdIDsOJLx1gvajjlm1D7cteNTT/f9/dHS0gQ4QxupEG@oAIZA2AfKNYmNjAQ)

Boring and straightforward.

```
             ⌋    The output is the minimum of
{          }ᶠ     every possible
          √       square root of
         +        a sum of
      ^₂ᵐ         the squares of
    -ᵐ            the differences between
   z              the coordinates for each axis
 ⊇                for a sublist of the input
  Ċ               containing two elements.
```

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 86 bytes

```javascript
a=>a.map(m=([x,y,z],i)=>a.map(([X,Y,Z])=>m=!i--|(d=Math.hypot(x-X,y-Y,z-Z))>m?m:d))&&m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY3NCoJAFIX3PYVt5A7ckaxWwdgTtFeHWQz@5ITjSEqo9O6TE0kFEZzF4eN8nIu8yS67qranjckLWzIrWSQDLVvQDPiAI04CFVkg8BgTTMUMNFsrSu@Qs5Psq6AaW9PDQGMcaYITTQmJ9FEfckJ8X9vMNJ2pi6A2ZyiB8w16LgI9HqLn4ur@SbdCELL6bYQvY5Hd/F3n7P7IH7Ov59mwDw)

#### Commented

```javascript
a =>                          // a[] = list of triplets
  a.map(m = ([x, y, z], i) => // for each triplet (x,y,z) at position i in a[]:
    a.map(([X, Y, Z]) =>      //   for each triplet (X,Y,Z) in a[]:
      m =                     //     update the minimum distance m:
        !i-- | (              //       decrement i; if it was equal to 0
          d = Math.hypot(     //       or the Euclidean distance d:
            x - X,            //         between (x,y,z)
            y - Y,            //         and (X,Y,Z)
            z - Z             //
        )) > m ?              //       is greater than m:
          m                   //         leave m unchanged
        :                     //       else:
          d                   //         update m to d
    )                         //   end of inner map()
  ) && m                      // end of outer map(); return m
```

Comment: How did I not know there was a [`Math.hypot`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/hypot) function?!  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 10 bytes

```
▼ṁẊȯ√ṁ□z-Ṗ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9G0PQ93Nj7c1XVi/aOOWUDmo2kLq3Qf7pz2////6GgDHSCM1Yk21AFCIG0C5BvFxgIA)

```
▼           # minimum of
 ṁ          # sums of applying function to
         Ṗ  # all subsets of input
            # (this may include subsets of >2 points,
            # but that's ok...)
  Ẋȯ√ṁ□z-   # the function:
  Ẋȯ        # apply to all adjacent pairs
            # (...that's why it was ok if there were >2 points
            # in any sublist)
    √       # square root of
     ṁ□     # sum of squres of
       z-   # element-wise differences
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>75</s> 74 bytes

```hs
g[]=[]
g(x:t)=[(sum$zipWith((**2).)(map(-)x)z)**0.5|z<-t]++g t
f=minimum.g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY5NboMwEIX3nGIUdWGDsWx@AolCT9CuuujCtSrUErAaE1SMilDuTh2gIq1Uz2I8b9737CpvP4rTaRxLITMhnRL1e4MzgdpO3w2qeVamQsh1A0wx0nmDfNzjAbsuo/FlOPhGel4JxjlmWtVKd5qWo85VDRlY9@MrNJ15Mp8PNQhwoK3OX9CcVW1a8DzYvNRF3xRvZg@b6zytZ6V4XwxwPf79jQHB8ScDL6YNXByrLypZMzAc/OllQEIwYksSwYkt2yM7B1IS4DQJAxazlCXxNk2TJMBkRfiEzKgFls5IOKMRjwIextsgTEK2i/ktyv5FrU7njQ1hlLPfZ/cnBdbL/PuJYtiapANy/AY)

```
g[]=[]        - edge case for combinations   
g(x:t)=[ ... |z<-t]++g t  
              - combinations
(sum$zipWith(\a b->(a-b)**2)x z)**0.5
              - compute hypo..
f=minimum.g   - return minimum value found
```

- Saved 1 thanks to @Unrelated String insane idea
  `(sum$zipWith(\a b->(a-b)**2)x z)**0.5` becomes
  `(sum$zipWith((**2).)(map(-)x)z)**0.5` e.g. we first map
  `x` to obtain a list of partially applied subtractions , then
  we zipWith `(**2).` (read "compose with square") which firstly finishes the subtraction
  and then computes the square.
  If I understood correctly O.o

Comment: [74 bytes](https://tio.run/##dY5NboMwEIX3nGIUdWGDsWx@AolCT9CuuujCtSrUErAaE1SMilDuTh2gIq1Uz2I8b9737CpvP4rTaRxLITMhnRL1e4MzgdpO3w2qeVamQsh1A0wx0nmDfNzjAbsuo/FlOPhGel4JxjlmWtVKd5qWo85VDRlY9@MrNJ15Mp8PNQhwoK3OX9CcVW1a8DzYvNRF3xRvZg@b6zytZ6V4XwxwPf79jQHB8ScDL6YNXByrLypZMzAc/OllQEIwYksSwYkt2yM7B1IS4DQJAxazlCXxNk2TJMBkRfiEzKgFls5IOKMRjwIextsgTEK2i/ktyv5FrU7njQ1hlLPfZ/cnBdbL/PuJYtiapANy/AY). Had the insane idea of getting rid of that lambda, and it happened to work

Comment: I say very insane @Unrelated String! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

### [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/)/MATLAB with Statistics package/toolbox, 17 bytes

```matlab
@(x)min(pdist(x))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999Bo0IzNzNPoyAls7gEyNb8n6YRbaAAhNYKhiBorWAC5BnFanIhJLDK/wcA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-g`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), <s>15</s> 14 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

The spec asks us to get the minimum but the lone test case gets the maximum so I don't know which to output. I've gone with the former but if that's not right then use the `-h` flag instead.

```
à2 ËÕËrnÃx²¬ÃÍ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LWc&code=4DIgy9XLcm7DeLKsw80&input=WwpbMCAwIDBdClsxIDEgMV0KWzQgMCAyXQpd)

Answer (score 2):

## Scala 3, 72 bytes

```scala
s=>math.sqrt((for> <-s;| <-s- >yield(>zip|map(_-_)map(x=>x*x)).sum).min)
```

[Try it online!](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/wDvJ0ypcS7CkSAvEl5klFg)

Accepts a `Set[List[Int]]` so that it can use `-` to ensure a point is not compared to itself.

This is my first time using Scala 3's new control syntax to save 2 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 29 bytes

```
[:<./@,+/&.:*:@:-"1/~+_*[:=#\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/o61s9PQddLT11fSstKwcrHSVDPXrtOO1oq1slWP@a3JxpSZn5CtoWKdpKmgYAPUZ6CgYgqCOgo6VCZBvpPkfAA)

```
[:<./@,+/&.:*:@:-"1/~+_*[:=#\
                           #\ 1…N
                        [:=   identity matrix NxN
                      _*      times infinity
                     +        plus
                 "1/~         the table with the coordinate triples:
              @:-             a - b and
         &.:*:                under square
       +/                     summed
         &.:*:                reverse square
[:<./@,                       flatten the table and get the min entry
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-MList::Util=min,sum`, <s>81</s> 77 bytes

*@KjetilS shaved 4 bytes.*

```perl
sub f{min map{@b=@$_;map{sqrt sum map($_-$b[$j++%3])**2,@$_}@_[++$i..$#_]}@_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY67CoMwGIX3PkWgf0FNlGjrYhB8gHbsFEJQqJDirSYORXz1pr9jyxnOhW8402Pucu/t0pB27c1A@npaq6asQIs92tfsiF36fQ9Ax9BIeFJ6OqswijKG2FZpSSmYJIGjVtg2b@s3aQPJGUoxmTIU@gV7pkJxAFNy8Qf9wqHwn3FyZhysj295wlOOfjXWFcXdma7EqwxvfQE)

Comment: Nice answer. Can loose 4 bytes with: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY67CoMwGIX3PkWgf0FNlGjrYhB8gHbsFEJQqJDirSYORXz1pr9jyxnOhW8402Pucu/t0pB27c1A@npaq6asQIs92tfsiF36fQ9Ax9BIeFJ6OqswijKG2FZpSSmYJIGjVtg2b@s3aQPJGUoxmTIU@gV7pkJxAFNy8Qf9wqHwn3FyZhysj295wlOOfjXWFcXdma7EqwxvfQE "Perl 5 – Try It Online")  No need to generalize to x dimensions when question says 3.

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>155</s> 147 bytes

Thanks to ceilingcat for -8 and an interesting (ab)use of `hypot`!

Takes a counted array of coordinates.

```c
#define g(x)hypot(c[x+j]-c[x+i],
i,j;float f(s,c,d,l)float*c,d,l;{for(l=-1,s*=3,i=0;i<s;i+=3)for(j=i;(j+=3)<s;l=l<0|d<l?d:l)d=g(2)g(1)g()0)));s=l;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZDdUoMwEIXv8xQ7deokEDq06I0h@iC1F5gQXCYSh1D/al9dDMF21MlkNnv2zNkPVNYoNY4XujbY1dDQN/b4/uwGqrZvabvLpoI7TpC3wlhXDWCo54prblnsk/gWB@N6amW25j6RBUeZCyy9wFQWbBq1EgVtpy6oVtoy/9SlvdM3lmnZ0A1r6DpcljPGhJdWHMcL7JTd6xpKP2h0q8db8key@DBpBLsBnirs6ItDzeBAAGbSRDnXay@CMHmQQ8tBuX03CDKZAlbsAit4VXWGLpZ6weES2W2QTF/XdI5gcyzA3EpVWesULZKQ6fGjdobGlYE92uYvDhltGTyhpCmLAzgvMtOiOW7b7lgkAnjuA2nkuIGlue@CKU0jJA8/HjmceKY9R3IcC8jjWcdzFV4bcnVW5tnmpxbk@uz@N4H1KmrklPcr9UsZWzV@zOzTmL1@Aw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 22 bytes

```
Ｉ₂⌊ΦＥθ⌊Ｅ…θκΣＸＥλ⁻ν§ιξ²κ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYpPC8IgGMa/ynt8BYNY3TqFEHQYjHYUD2LCZE43p7U@vTkpeOD591ODDMpLm3MXjIvI5BqxX5IM@uF9xNY4M6UJb8ZGHbCVMy4U/ute2UdZzQZfj5FQ6MvR@fePtpVOKzoK13h3T72hobARUtCGkOpj9UvOnPMjhV2CAm8KUbTHc11PQoh8eNkv) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes `n`-dimensional vectors. Explanation:

```
     θ                  Input list
    Ｅ                   Map over vectors
         θ              Input list
        …               Truncate to length
          κ             Outer index
       Ｅ                Map over remaining vectors
              λ         Inner vector
             Ｅ          Map over coordinates
                 §ιξ    Coordinate of outer vector
                ν       Current coordinate
               ⁻        Difference
            Ｘ       ²   Squared
           Σ            Summed
      ⌊                 Take the minimum square sum
   Φ                 κ  Filter out minimum of empty list
  ⌊                     Take the minimum
 ₂                      Take the square root
Ｉ                       Cast to string
                        Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 67 bytes

```
[ dup [ v- norm ] cartesian-map [ head ] map-index concat infimum ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZU4xDsJADNvvFeYBRYCY4AGIhQUxVQzRNVVP0GvJ5RAI9e0lrcSEvDi2I7smr52Ml/PxdNihljduLJHvaEmb5ZMnNyHxI3P0nNALq757CVGxd8fTDskLqW@cW0A5KULssyb3ccDHsJoxGFvPmNjWlI2x4S/znx7cMJaoco8SzwKxkxZXeBIrCxSLlianYapMtqMIseIXfBc9TWPq0Gb7GM36LeyyzhOX8HcmGb8)

Evaluates self-cartesian-product by vector distance, takes the lower triangular matrix (without diagonals), and evaluates the minimum of all values.

```
[                                ! anonymous lambda
  dup [ v- norm ] cartesian-map  ! self-cartesian-product by vector distance
  [ head ] map-index             ! for each array at index i, take first i elems
  concat infimum                 ! minimum of all values
]
```

---

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 73 bytes

```
USE: math.combinatorics
[ 2 [ first2 v- norm ] map-combinations infimum ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY/BagJBDIbv8xTpAyit9LQ9l@LFi3iSHsYxq6FuZk0ygsg@@xpn60l@CB/Jn/CnjcmyjJv1cvXTwB8K4wm6aMda5hL5gDpxlj3KhBd8bP3328LJKLNCL2h27YXYQPFckJMvK5qXLEZ8gK@wXDWgSaKlYwhvYKgGxH0xDbcAcHO9Vw1OH1UP@vTOwml48by6hzD4R9/NlC/lbkccPTAlDVu/soWWRG0Blxlwlg5@3dnPnsb6C3FLXfHR6KNnzlysBp1DOmGU8Q4)

Factor has a built-in for generating combinations, but it is way too long (`USE: math.combinatorics map-combinations` is already 40 bytes).

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 79 bytes

I'm new here and not completely sure this follows the rules, LMK if this isn't valid!

```python
lambda p:min(sum((a-b)**2for a,b in zip(x,y))**.5for x in p for y in p if x!=y)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `ḋ`, 9 bytes

```
∪2ḋƛ÷∆d;g
```

```
∪           # Delete duplicates
 2ḋ         # All subsets of length 2
   ƛ÷∆d;    # Euclidean distance of every subset
        g   # Minimum
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyLhuIsiLCIiLCLiiKoy4biLxpvDt+KIhmQ7ZyIsIiIsIltbMCwwLDBdLFswLDAsMF0sWzEsMSwxXSxbMiwyLDJdXSJd)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 82 bytes

```python
f=lambda a,*b:[*b]and[min([sum((x-y)**2for x,y in zip(a,q))**.5for q in b]+f(*b))]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY7NCsIwEITvPkWOu3EtaauXQp8k5JBQiwGb/kVoffmY2JwETzP7zbDMtPvH6OoQ@vapB9NppombRnKjtOvkYB3I9TUAbJcdOa/6cWEb7cw69rYTaJox4uKW@JyoUeceuEFUITF/X33CEgQJKpGgjCqiCqqyCqpRUa6Iv5XIiyP5KZffv9d4V0eUEctGNSfGpsU6D3FaWoQYPg)

---

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/) with SciPy, 58 bytes

```python
lambda*a:min(pdist(a))
from scipy.spatial.distance import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY67DoMwDEV3vsJjgiIUoBNSv6RlcIGolshDiRe@Pg0lU6VOx77nynI4@O3dmM39mXe0rxVbnCw5EVZKLFDKxkRvIS0Uji4FZMK9Ox26ZQOywUdus/EReEsM5OAhtNKql0r0hbpQq6FSq1HOqlb030rJu8v8lPvv3VvZh0vVCOowTw1AiORYGNGeH0mZPw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Fortran (GFortran)](https://gcc.gnu.org/fortran/), <s>206</s> <s>182</s> <s>148</s> 144 bytes

```fortran
function d(A,n);real A(3,n);t=0
do 5 k=1,n-1;do 5 j=2,n;s=0;do i=1,3;s=s+(A(i,k)-A(i,j))**2;enddo
5 if(t==0)t=s;if(s>0.and.t>s)t=s;d=sqrt(t);end
```

[try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY3BDoMgEETvfAVHoGhQ24MSTPwUU6RBDbaw/X66aLOHnTfJzLgjQpxD9XKXyHGZ92GYWCf7nmskK2T4f8Ym5uXKpTeN7Lhc8QWu39EHENKyCYkswWb3DU/wR6CXV@I7LZ2owShiD/qgW0lXjT5hNS3OJKMKnvUI6XYObry6drkQrcZ@e5AH9Y6BMYqDSRp1GlU9B1vDmE7LmvSJwICXQM4dURSPNBSP3FG3Pw)
 <s><sub>[148bytes](https://tio.run/##PY7RboMwDEXf8xV5jJmpAqwPbZRKfApbwhSKzJa4308dWk1@8L2WfY/nLXOeqP2ZX2LPcVqv19EMeLmAExcapHc3ZjQJF8DkOxwAF2kE6ntaVx3MiIQR1G9OxA1GFSns5fGVtwcniv8LNWvVFUDg2FsVNn3W9xrVdu4wi@@FWbyt9mCJKR8H/Q7t6wlomt4JI2zqrNNs2HsL7IsTXW72NFE48a0co@jLX2bDUA/2fVBWS6lOS6lP0f0T)</sub></s>
 <s><sub>[182bytes](https://tio.run/##LYzNDoQgDITvPIVHyqJB3YuSmvgoJugG3eDy8/5sRdOkM18z0@0MKSyu/my3yTmsy3ccZ97LYQBNZIR0j3I@cyt3kBZb2YPcSRzohIqZszouqltNdseOShHVBSVMEF@lfkB9fwEhOr06Y07mMfqQeARtN54QFST0l/eTahZnmjT5cirxZ/@CdUnIdGHOPVMVDWsrGvYm3/0B)</sub></s>
 <s><sub>[206bytes](https://tio.run/##NYzdDoMgDIXveQovqavGn11BMPFR2MAFJTiQ93f1Z2nSfqfntNOactKh@kwX7Huy2qP2fn3rrF/eCjFygQIkGabEIG/P8pH3GOBvcNIOZ0CnWuwBZxoBmFmL5aCqlYSz6ujDpppDnEES2@M8XaC6PkBZdtIGY1YW1RZT5htIN/GsVANZxYPj0NQ6mDoP8Vyd8bt/kwu5xMxI7nvPmoKKtQUVexJ3Pw)</sub></s>

*line 1: sets up array, reads in data
*line 2: iterates over rows `j`,`k`, and sums the difference-squares
*line 3: initialises min distance `t`, compares current Euclidean squared distance `s`, taking the lower number, and ignores a distance of `0` (dupe points)

<sub>Saved ***24 bytes*** by removing the `allocate` stuff and giving the array preset dimensions. A possible improvement for my other Fortran answers!

Saved another ***34 bytes*** by using a subroutine and moving I/O to the main program. Replaced repeated `enddo`s with a line number. Removed a placeholder variable `q`. Some inspiration taken from [this fortran golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/206044/15940). I went looking for a useful intrinsic like [NORM2](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/NORM2.html#NORM2) or [HYPOT](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/HYPOT.html#HYPOT) but couldn't find one for this problem.

Saved ***4 bytes*** by replacing the `subroutine` with a `function`</sub>

Comment: Unfortunately there's a Heisenbug in this code, it occasionally spits out something insane. Looks like a floating point error. Can't pinpoint it

Comment: Fixed it by setting `t=0` in the first line. :)

Answer (score 0):

## [Julia 1.8](http://julialang.org/), 52 bytes

```julia
a>b...=min(>(b...),@.splat(hypot)(b-[a])...)
>()=Inf
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY1BT8QgEIXv/IpJvMwklLTqwUuJV038BU0Psy5VNiwlFI0m/vc6LOpN5vDgvW8ep7fgefjYr@B5PScu8FgNGMyd2lLgggvBCJxfts4uWNUYQzvbg@h49hEt1ivpe9MWXj/TWggP3cQz1URZpPEhLvuyZvDgI2THx@Cj25AUyGH5wr1zwCdX2CTOm0NPBObLgu/s5KVmvpAp@1hCRNmwYJFrPykXj/uEvZYhjYOWEb2V9zXNqiXDJWmE@D/a65s/ov@XEN@0pLK//U3nbw)

I feel like there is a better way but I can't figure it out. This will work for bigger dimensions as well

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 53 bytes

```julia
a>b...=min(>(b...),(b.|>i->hypot(a-i...))...)
>()=Inf
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dU4xDsIwDNz7Co@OlEYtsDY7Ay@oOhg1FUYhVG1BIPH34DTARizlnLvzOeebZ6ofMZI9GmOaCwe0mFqlBV6WS3t6jtcFqeTEqnQVFlWzD0McrhMwcIDJUe85uBlVAXIIGnB38nhwC5mRptkhKwWSCBLZpqxudY4Th8UHlAkLFmldUrjQxxYrLSUfqbWU4E7eG9UVWalXJTuE/2Cltz9H9dchvMlK8n7zM3Zv)